# How can I test Firebase Push Notification during development without publishing app to playstore?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I am trying to incorporate Firebase Push Notifications on my existing android app following the guides from [the developer site](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-audience).

After successfully building the application how can I test if Firebase Notifications is working or not without publishing the app to playstore?

The relevant files look like this:

services/FirebaseMessagingService.java

```
public class FirebaseNotificationService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseMsgService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        String messageBody = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NavActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

ApplicationManifest.xml

```
<service android:name="services.FirebaseNotificationService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.1'
}
```

Comment: Well you can test it by going to the Firebase Console and sending a Push Notification. ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "working properly or not"? What feature are you trying to confirm?

Comment: I practically want to make sure that the notifications sent from Firebase Console are reaching my device and I can see them or take some action based on notification receiving.

Answer (score 1):

Run your app through USB debugging. It should work in order to test it. Alternativly, you can publish your app to alpha/beta and download it on your own devices and test it. Both ways work

All though the second way includes publishing it isn't complete publishing because it is only in closed alpha/beta that for an instance only you can have access to.

Comment: Thanks. Will it work on genymotion emulator without physical device?

Comment: doubt it. YOu need a real device for it as far as I know

Comment: You need the Play Services. Afaik Genymotion doesn't come with them but the Emulators with the Google API do afaik.

Comment: Well, I installed the app on a real device and sent notification message from firebase console, which has been almost 20 hours. Still no notification on the device and notification sent on console panel is still 0. I doubt whether I can test it without at least alpha/beta publishing.

Comment: is the notifications set up propperly? with the reciever and dependency in the gradle file and what not?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to a physical device would be using the [Genymotion emulator](https://www.genymotion.com/) to test them, just make sure you follow this guide (very simple) to install Google Play: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952